# creating my own Concat function (SML)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I need to create my own concat function and am confused how I get the output I need. Example:

> myconcat(["a", "b", "c"]) returns "abc"
>
> ([]) returns ""

I have this:

```
fun myconcat ([],L2) = L2
| myconcat(x::xs, L2) = x::myconcat(xs,L2);
```

Which just returns a list of my two strings. How would I get them to output what i need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't appear to have the correct type, to start with.
The example has type `string list -> string`, where your function seems to have type `'a list * 'a list -> 'a list`.

To concatenate two strings, you would use `^`, not `::`.

The former has type `string * string -> string`, while the latter has type `'a * 'a list -> 'a list`. As strings are not lists in SML, trying to concatenate them with `::` will cause a
type error.

To actually do what you want, in the simplest way, try

```
fun myconcat L = foldr (op^) "" L
```

Comment: To expand on that, `fun myconcat L = foldr (fn (s1, result) => s1 ^ result) "" L`